# redirect to another page in specific datetime using jquery

Tags: jquery, datetime

I am working on online exam system, every student can take that exam between start date and end date  I have start date and end date in exam table in my data base, I have exam page and I need to redirect the student to another page at the end `datetime` end end time is equal to all of the students first I tried `sessions` but it did not work I found out that I need to use `jQuery` for doing something like this as I am new to all this I am wondering how can I do such a thing.

Comment: Would it not be better to use php fir this? Since JavaScript (jquery) is done in the students browsers, they can also easy fool the time check. Else, javascript can also do the job, no special jquery needed.

Comment: @Timo002 the problem with using php is that the php does not dynamically check the time

Comment: Why do you dynamically want to check? Do they only have eg 60 minutes to take the exam?

Comment: for example they have to start the exam at 8:00 am till 9:00 am if someone logs in at 8:30 am he can take the exam but only till 9:00 am

Comment: You will have to do such checks server side.  If you do them client side (using jquery or other tool kit) the student can simply edit the page as a local page or using a browser plugin and simply by-pass your check.

Comment: .. or the user can simply just change their laptops clock and get extra time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be do this on the side of the server, any time the students interact with it. The benefot could be that they could not alter the code (which they can in case of client side scirpt which runs on their machines). If the application would be let's say in PHP, you could use something like

```
<?php

// get the end time from thedatbaase
$endTime = get_end_time();

// check if the test is not over
if(time() > $endTime ) {
  header("Location: /path/to/this-test-is-closed.php");
  die();
}
```

Also, you could add simple JavaScript countdown on the page that will not redirect people away, but would just tell them how much time is left. But the check itself would be on the server.